# Not understanding when to use NextJS 13 API routes

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a very basic NextJS 13 blog project, using mongodb as the database and mongoose. Right now, this is how I use the API route handlers to populate my Home component with posts:

app/api/posts/route.js

```
import Post from "@models/post";
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async () => {
    try {
        await connectToDB();

        const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });

        return NextResponse.json(posts);
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
    }
};
```

app/posts/page.js

```
import { fetchPosts } from "@utils/api/posts";
import Link from "next/link";

export default async function Home() {
    const posts = await fetchPosts();

    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => (
                <Link href={`/posts/${post._id}`} key={post._id}>
                    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

utils/api/posts.js

```
export async function fetchPosts() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/posts")

    const data = await res.json();

    console.log(data);

    return data;
}
```

The thing is, isn't it bad to make a fetch call to localhost:3000 when I am already on localhost:3000? I mean, I could simply access the posts directly in my Home component, like this:

```
async function getPosts() {
    await connectToDB();

    const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });

    return posts;
}

export default async function Home() {
    const posts = await getPosts();

    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => (
                <Link href={`/posts/${post._id}`} key={post._id}>
                    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried this approach and it works fine. But which one is better and best practice?

Comment: Yes, I'm also using the second approach and then you can reuse the getPosts() function you declared here in your API route handler, so you don't duplicate the post fetching logic